# Google Classroom - Create Course Error PHP

Tags: php, google-classroom

I'm trying to create a course using the Google_Service_Classroom API, using PHP, but I get an error in the call.

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=C:\laragon\www\classroom.json');

$user_admin= 'test00001@gmail.com';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setSubject($user_admin);

$client->setScopes(array(

    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.emails',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.photos'

));
$service = new Google_Service_Classroom($client);

$postBody = array(
    "id" => "1",
    "name" => "Course 01",
    "section" => "15/19",
    "descriptionHeading" => "Course 01 test 001",
    "description" => "Course 01 test",
    "room" => "03/12",
    "creationTime" => "2020-12-12T11:48:50.951Z",
    "enrollmentCode" => "yzdeeee",
    "courseState" => "ACTIVE",
    "alternateLink" => "https://classroom.google.com/c/coursetest01"
);

$optParams = array();
$results = $service->courses->create($postBody, $optParams);

echo '<pre>', print_r($results, true);
exit;
```

My return:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Google_Service_Classroom_Resource_Courses::create() must be an instance of Google_Service_Classroom_Course, array given, called in C:\laragon\www\teste-03.php on line 41 and defined in C:\laragon\www\vendor\google\apiclient-services\src\Google\Service\Classroom\Resource\Courses.php:47 Stack trace: #0 C:\laragon\www\teste-03.php(41): Google_Service_Classroom_Resource_Courses->create(Array, Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\laragon\www\vendor\google\apiclient-services\src\Google\Service\Classroom\Resource\Courses.php on line 47
```

I'm seeing the documents, but I don't see where to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is self-explanatory. It says `Argument 1 passed to Google_Service_Classroom_Resource_Courses::create() must be an instance of Google_Service_Classroom_Course, array given` and this occurs because `$postBody` is an array.

As shown in the documentation of function `create`

```php
create( Google_Service_Classroom_Course $postBody, array $optParams = array() )
```

this function expects the first parameter to be a `Google_Service_Classroom_Course` object instead of an array. So you need to first create an object of this type and then pass this object as parameter.
So the end result should be like:

```php
$course = new Google_Service_Classroom_Course(array(
    "id" => "1",
    "name" => "Course 01",
    "section" => "15/19",
    "descriptionHeading" => "Course 01 test 001",
    "description" => "Course 01 test",
    "room" => "03/12",
    "creationTime" => "2020-12-12T11:48:50.951Z",
    "enrollmentCode" => "yzdeeee",
    "courseState" => "ACTIVE",
    "alternateLink" => "https://classroom.google.com/c/coursetest01"
));


$course = $service->courses->create($course);
```

note: since the second parameter has a default value of empty array (`array $optParams = array()`) it is not necessary to include it explicitly. The last line of the above is exactly the same with:

```php
$optParams = array();
$course = $service->courses->create($course, $optParams);
```

Also have in mind that since `$course` is an object its not advised to print it like you do with arrays. You can instead print specific info of the object like:

```php
printf("Course created: %s (%s)\n", $course->name, $course->id);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!